# How non-$PV$ work is handled in thermodynamic identities?

Tags: thermodynamics, work

Schroeder chapter 5 discusses the following relationships between work and potentials $F$ and $G$

$$\Delta F\le W$$

$$\Delta G \le W_{other}$$

where $W$ corresponds to any kind of work done *on* system, not just $PV$ work, ie. $W=-P\Delta V+W_{other}$ where $W_{other}$ is non-$PV$ work like electrical work. I am wondering what is the exact formula for $W_{other}$, so I am a bit confused how the following identities take account of non-$PV$ work.

$$dF=-SdT-PdV+\sum_i \mu_i dN_i$$

$$dG=-SdT+VdP+\sum_i \mu_i dN_i$$

I understand that the term $-PdV$ in $dF$ corresponds to PV work, so that means

$$W_{other}=\sum_i \mu_i dN_i$$

right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact formula for $W_{other}$ - it's an umbrella term. For instance, it could include [other types of mechanical work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(thermodynamics)#Other_mechanical_types_of_work) like spring work where $W = \frac{1}{2}k(x_1^2-x_2^2)$ or various types of non-mechanical work like electrical work, where $W = \int IV dt$ (see for instance, Problem 14.3 in Blundell and Blundell). In fact, the formula you have for $W_{other}$ is its own kind of work - *chemical* work.

We can answer your broader question by looking at how these thermodynamic identities are derived. We always start with the first law:

$$dU = \delta Q + \delta W$$

We have that $\delta Q = TdS$ (this is from Clausius' theorem and holds only for a reversible process). The rest of the fundamental thermodynamic relation generally comes from analyzing the Carnot cycle, where the types of work that matter are $\delta W_{mech} = -PdV$ and $\delta W_{chem} = \sum\limits_i \mu_i dN_i$ - but *in general* we can write

$$dU = TdS  + \delta W_{tot}$$

Where $\delta W_{tot} = W_{mech} + W_{chem} + \cdots$. The rest of the thermodynamic identities come from manipulating this fundamental thermodynamic identity so that our function has different natural variables. Notice that if we write $\delta W_{tot} = W_{mech} + W_{chem}$ (i.e., these are the only relevant types of work for our system) then our natural variables for $U$ are $S, V, \{N_i\}$. From this relation we get definitions of $T, P, \mu$ - but notice to get $P, \mu$ we have to hold $S$ constant - that's hard! So we want to have thermodynamic quantities that don't have $S$ has a natural variable. (Similarly, we may want to define thermodynamic quantities that have $P$ or $\{\mu_i\}$ as a natural variable instead of $V, \{N_i\}$.)

Thus, we do what is technically a Legendre transform (and Schroeder I believe mentions that these variables $S$ and $T$, $P$ and $V$, $\mu_i$ and $N_i$, etc. - are conjugate variables, and there's various interesting things we can go into here but I'm already off in the weeds a bit) but in practice is basically screwing around with the product rule. We can write $d(ST) = TdS + SdT$, for instance, and so have

$$d(U-ST) = dU - TdS - SdT = -SdT + \delta W_{tot} = dF$$

Where we *define* $F = U - ST$ because we have obtained a function that has $T$ as a natural variable instead of $S$. That's all that's happening in the derivation of thermodynamic identities: we start with the first law, realize we want a function in terms of a different set of variables, mess around with the product rule, define our function as the product rule indicates. With this set of rules, it *doesn't matter* what our formulas for work are - we can throw them in as another term and deal with them appropriately!

Let's say for instance that we have a system where we care about mechanical work, chemical work, and electrical work. Then we have $$\delta W = -PdV + \sum\limits_i \mu_i dN_i + \int IV dt$$ and $$dU = TdS -PdV + \sum\limits_i \mu_i dN_i + \int IV dt$$ - but we're interested in a system with $P$ as a natural variable instead of $V$. We have $d(PV) = VdP + PdV$ so we have $$d(U+PV) = TdS + VdP + \sum\limits_i \mu_i dN_i + \int IV dt = dH$$

Where we define $H = U+PV$. See what happened here? That extra $W_{other}$ just came along for the ride. Those identities take account of that other work by *ignoring* it because it often isn't relevant for thermodynamic systems in textbooks! Most gases do not care about types of work other than mechanical and chemical.

What Schroeder is doing in Chapter 5 is using these identities to talk about how $\Delta G, \Delta H, \Delta F$ can be thought about in terms of work. All of these measure the capacity of a system to do different types of work under different conditions. $\Delta G$ is the maximum amount of nonmechanical work that can be done under constant $T, P, N$, for instance. You'll also notice that the potentials we've talked about so far only don't look at changing natural variables to $\mu_i$ - we can also talk about the *grand potential*. Working through deriving this, as in Problem 5.23 in Schroeder, is a nice way to see how the process works. (And, it also gives an idea of how, in some sense, these potentials are arbitrary - they're defined and taught because they're convenient quantities! You could theoretically define a potential whose natural variables depend on some term in $W_{other}$.)

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer but there is one thing that makes me uncomfortable. Are you sure that you can replace $\delta Q$ in the first law with $TdS$? When deriving thermodynamic identities, we are assuming that all processes are reversible, no?

Comment: BTW, you forgot to insert + between $PdV$ and $\sum_i \mu_i dN_i$ in the $d(U+PV)$ equation.

Comment: @RaySiplao ah, thanks for the catch! As for your question  - I'm pulling from Clausius' theorem which says that $\delta Q = TdS$ for a reversible process. As long as our other forms of work are not volume or number dependent, this definition holds, I believe. There's also some discussion of this in section 3.3-3.4 of Schroeder, and you can also reference our definition of temperature in eqn 3.5.

Comment: Oh, sorry there is another error I overlooked before. In $dH$ equation again, $PdV$ should be $VdP$.

Comment: @RaySiplao Ack, errors left and right. Thanks!